# How would I check if a part of a string equals another string of unknown length?

Tags: java, string

```
        for(int j = 1;j<fileArray.size();j++) {
            if(str.contains(fileArray.get(end+j))) {

            }
        }
```

(assume end is some number such as 30).
The goal of this part is when having a window length of 30 and a fileArray size > 30, check if theres anything after index 30 that matches whatever is inside the window.
  ex: "i like to eat piesss aaaabbbbpiesssbbbb" 
          starting from the beginning of the string add the first 17 characters to a arraylist called window. then i check the rest of the string starting from right after window to see if there's anything that matches. space doesnt match so you add it to the output. keep checking then you see "piesss" matches. Then i replace the second "piesss" with wherever the first "piesss" occurs.

So right now im using fileArray.get(end+j) to check if there's anything that matches within my string(str) except this doesn't really work. Is there a way I could fix this code segment?

Comment: Start over. What are you actually trying to do? Your question needs a little more information, what is it not doing (or doing) that is undesirable? How do you know? why are you not accessing `fileArray.get(j)` since that's what you're iterating?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry i edited the question, and fileArray.get(j) is already being accessed. I just didn't paste all my code

Comment: No, I sill don't understand your question... a moving a text window that searches right for matches.... for what? why is "piesss" (a sub-string) a match? How do you replace the "piesss"(es)? What does it accomplish?

Comment: aaaabbbbpiesssbbbb is 18 characters not 17

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it searches for any substring with a length greater than 5 that will match with what is inside the window

Comment: For what purpose does it do this? What problem does that allow you to solve?

Comment: If you replace the second piesss with the first piesss nothing will change.  Could you make the replacement instructions a little clearer.  Please do so by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement part of your question is still unclear.  As is any reasoning to use an ArrayList.  I've written some code that does a 5 character window search for a match after splitting the string you provided.  Note how with the 30 and 17 values you gave nothing is ever matched (see commented out code).  However with tweaked values some matches can be found.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                 //          1         2         3   
                 //012345678901234567890123456789012345678   <- shows the index 
    String test = "i like to eat piesss aaaabbbbpiesssbbbb";
//    int first = 17;
//    int end = 30;

    int first = 20;
    int end = 37;

    String firstHalf = test.substring(0, first);
    String secondHalf = test.substring(first, end);

    int matchSize = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i + matchSize < secondHalf.length() ; i++)
    {
        String window = secondHalf.substring(i, i + matchSize);
        if ( firstHalf.contains(window) )
        {
            System.out.println(window);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done searching.");
}
```

Displays:

```
piess
iesss
Done searching.
```

If this isn't what you meant PLEASE edit your question to make your needs clear.